# Audio not playing through receiver

Tags: windows-8, audio, video, hdmi

i am trying to get audio to play tough my [Onkyo TX-NR616 7.2- Channel THX Select2 Plus Certified Network A/V Receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0077V88W2).

It was intially working then the whole system was powered down and when I turned it back on I could get video working but not audio.

I am currenltly running from my pc to the in pc slot (hdmi 6) and out to my tv (hdmi out).

I also hooked up my xbox in place of my pc to try and see if it was a pc issues but it was the same result. Video worked fine but no audio.

The system is about 2 months old so hardware problems would seem a bit of a stretch. Also since audio was working yesterday, I dont think its a connection issue.

Also I went back through the setup test, and when it got to speaker config check, the speakers registered as being there. Which would again reenforce that its not a connection.

I am new to av so I am guessing I am missing something simple.

Comment: Do you by chance have a Haswell chip? [Many people](https://www.google.com/search?q=4600+hdmi+no+audio+site:communities.intel.com) with Intel 4400 and 4600 graphics are having this problem. Intel is [working on it](https://communities.intel.com/message/218663#218663). In the meantime, using an [older driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23106) has solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if "listening mode" is set to disperse audio to speakers that don't exist instead of the hdmi output only. Make sure there is no interference from an optical cable, that may require more setup. Try turning off your TV **only** while everything else is on. I have had tvs that become finicky with hdmi inputs from time to time. Make sure your PC's default realtech audio device is the specific hdmi output it is supposed to be. Also try changing input ports (ie try game port hdmi and press the appropriate button on the front). If you have other hdmi cables around i would try swapping them too. This problem can be caused by many things on the Onkyos (old and new), but most of my problems in the past have been minor settings recieving/diverting the sound where it is not supposed to be.